# Can Cobertura instrument custom java annotations?

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura

I have a simple annotation like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface FragmentConfiguration {
    public static enum ViewMode {
        WithActionBar, WithMenuFragment, FullScreen
    };

    ViewMode viewMode() default ViewMode.WithActionBar;
}
```

If I run my classes folder then through Cobertua 1.9.4.1 it creates the expected `FragmentConfiguration$ViewMode.class`, but not the expected `FragmentConfiguration.class` in the target directory, obviously both exist in the source folder and are not excluded either. The output of Cobertura also does not issue a warning or anything else, but just happily reports that it instrumented so-and-so-many files.

Even if I move the enum out of the interface definition, then Cobertura still does not instrument the file. So can I somehow enable a more verbose mode to see what Cobertura does or rather not does or what can I do to resolve the problem?

Right now I copy the original (uninstrumented) class file over from my classes directory to let my tests still run through...

Comment: there is nothing to cover in that annotation, so why would you need to instrument it?

Comment: Thats understood, the problem is just that if one targets the instrumented class dir as solely class path, the class is missing and therefor the code throws ClassNotFound exceptions on runtime. I'd have expected that Cobertura would have at least copied over the class files it doesn't have to / need to instrument from the source directory...